# How to interpret Google Cloud ML Prediction results?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I worked through the **GC ML Census Wide & Deep Learning** example
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census

Given census data about a person such as age, gender, education and occupation (the features), this **DNNLinearCombinedClassifier** model should predict whether or not the person earns more than 50,000 dollars a year (the target label).

I ran an online prediction

`gcloud ml-engine predict --model census --version v1 --json-instances ../test.json`

using the test.json data

`{"age": 25, "workclass": " Private", "education": " 11th", "education_num": 7, "marital_status": " Never-married", "occupation": " Machine-op-inspct", "relationship": " Own-child", "race": " Black", "gender": " Male", "capital_gain": 0, "capital_loss": 0, "hours_per_week": 40, "native_country": " United-States"}`

I get the following result:

`{"probabilities": [0.9962924122810364, 0.003707568161189556], "logits": [-5.593664646148682], "classes": 0, "logistic": [0.003707568161189556]}`

How do I interpret this ?
my current understanding is that logit is the inverse of the sigmoid binary classification activation function in the output layer (not sure what the output numbers signify) and that `classes: 0` refers to a binary classification of < $50,000, as opposed to 1 (>= $50,000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

- **probabilities**: are the probabilities of < $50K vs >=$50K.
- **classes**: the predicted class (0, i.e. < $50K)
- [**logits**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit): ln(p/(1-p)) = ln(0.00371/(1-.00371)) = -5.593
- **logistic**: 1/(1+exp(-logit)) = 1/(1+exp(5.593)) = 0.0037

Comment: How are the class labels chosen? Is it based on the indices of the class labels defined in `LABELS` list?

Comment: @FayazAhmed That is correct. So LABELS[classes] gives you the string label.